# EF - pass null value to SQL column so default value gets inserted

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-6

SQL Server table T2 has 2 columns:

```
Id INT NOT NULL 
CreateDate DateTime NOT NULL, default = (getdate())
```

This statement inserts the CreateDate value correctly because it uses (getdate()) as default.

```
Insert T2 (Id)
Values (1)
```

So far so good. The problem is when I use Entity Framework to insert a row and still wish to use the default (`getdate()`) value.

Because the `CreateDate` is defined as `NOT NULL`, I cannot leave it blank or leave out of the Insert statement when using EF. But I want SQL to generate the timestamp on the server/database side.

Is there a way to handle this?

Comment: Slight detour...the name timestamp is a bad choice for a column name. It is the name of an existing datatype (which has nothing to do with time of day) and also it is incredibly ambiguous. I sense it is a time that something happened but what? The date it was inserted? The date it was updated? Use a meaningful name like DateCreated or something.

Comment: Sorry, it is not really called Timestamp. I was trying to write this up quick and strip down to basics. Agreed, bad name choice. I changed to CreateDate. Thanks.

Comment: Ahh gotcha....no biggie. I can't help with the EF stuff....I can't even spell it. :)

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341238/entity-framework-generates-values-for-not-null-columns-which-has-default-defined

Comment: Bravo squillman. I found the answer in that link. I posted full answer below. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to squillman's [reference to another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341238/entity-framework-generates-values-for-not-null-columns-which-has-default-defined), I was able to find the answer.

Go to EDMX diagram, and you can set the StoreGeneratedPattern property to achieve what I am trying to do.

There are three Database Generated Options

```
Computed : The database generates a value when a row is inserted or updated.
Identity : The database generates a value when a row is inserted.
None : The database does not generate values.
```

EDIT: Although the picture shows Identity, I had to change it to Computed. The reason is that Identity option only works if the row is Inserted only. If the row is ever updated (other columns updated), then it caused an error. The Computed option seems to work fine with Insert (runs the default script) and Updates (to other columns, default script does not run again).

[image]